# Excel - Count Each time yesterday's date and a second criteria appear on a different sheet

Tags: excel, formula

Hello and thanks in advance for the response.

I have an excel workbook in which Sheet 1 is a data table and Sheet 2 will contain a number of formulas that pull from Sheet 1.

Specifically, I have two columns in Sheet 1, one with dates and one with letters (A-D) and I want to count each time the date column is yesterday's date and the letter is A. NOTE: This needs to be a formula not VBA.

```
Col A: Date   --   Col B: Letter

Row 1: 11/13/2018--A

Row 2: 11/11/2018--B

Row 3: 11/02/2018--A

Row 4: 11/12/2018--B

Row 5: 11/13/2018--A

Row 6: 11/13/2018--A

Row 7: 11/13/2018--C

Row 8: 11/13/2018--C
```

In this case the formula in Sheet 2 should display a count of 3 since yesterday's date is 11/13/2018 and has the letter A 3 times.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!A1:A8=TODAY()-1),--(Sheet1!B1:B8="A"))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Date]=D1)*(Table1[Letter]=E1))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have actual dates and not strings that resemble dates you can use CountIfs as follows:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9,TODAY()-1,$B$2:$B$9,"A")
```